# Linux; U; Android 4.1.1 google tv

Tags: google-tv

How does one identify a google tv browser?  Google's FAQ (https://developers.google.com/tv/faq) says that the userAgent will have GoogleTV in it.  However, my Google TV user agent shows:

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; en-us; Android Build/JRO03H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30; ip: 68.44.182.200; sAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; en-us; Android Build/JRO03H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30;

How can I safely identify a Google TV versus say an Android phone?

Comment: It's a google tv stick.  Mini iMito MX1 Android mini PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official Google TV devices are all based on Android 3.2. You probably have an Android-based TV device which is not an official Google TV device.